# unable to install php5-mcrypt

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-13.04, mcrypt

I'm trying to install mcrypt under php and can't. If I do `php test.php | grep mcrypt` (where test.php contains `phpinfo()`) nothing comes up so I want to install it.

If I do `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` I get this:

```
E: Unable to locate package php5-mcrypt
```

If I do `sudo apt-cache search mcrypt` nothing comes up.

Here's my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring universe
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring universe
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates universe
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates universe
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring multiverse
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring multiverse
 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates multiverse
 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates multiverse
 deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
 deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
```

The last set of deb / deb-src stuff is from http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=135896

According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/19446679/569976 this should work:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Only problem: I do not have /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini.

Any ideas? Do I have to compile mcrypt myself from source to get it working on ubuntu? I'm running Ubuntu 13.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu universe` in `sources.list`, then `apt-get update` and `apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

Comment: """If I do php test.php | grep mcrypt""" -> nothing about the question but try php -i

Comment: @user2196728 - it says that line is malformed. I tried `deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu test universe` but am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you are having the same issue that I am (I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, and not 13.04), but this worked for myself. Here is the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446679/mcrypt-not-present-after-ubuntu-upgrade-to-13-10

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```